# The simplest way to save data into file from network on the iOS

Tags: ios, image, networking

I have URL like this: http://example.com/image.jpg
What the simplest way to save url's target content into the local file on the iOS (iPhone)?

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest way is the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:..];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *fileName = ..
[data writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];
```

Comment: +1 because the question asks for "simplest", which this certainly is. But note that "simplest" and "best" may not be the same thing -- you should almost always use an asynchronous method when pulling data from the net.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this would be to use the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) project. Primarily because it already has the required reachability checks built in and it is easy to setup and use asynchronous request.

Asynchronous download example from the site:

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}
```

Reachability comment from the site:

> It allows ASIHTTPRequest to be
>   notified when the network connection
>   changes from WWAN to WiFi, or
>   vice-versa.